# Reporting services 2008: Forcing Group footer at bottom of each page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to write a report which is to be printed on pre-printed paper, with a cheque at the bottom.  So the bottom location is fixed.

The data I have is a Header/Details scenario.  So a cheque (header), could contain any number of entries included on it (details).

The cheques are batched, so many can be printed at once fro the report.

The report should have all the details in the top 2/3 of the page (cropped to fit if required).  And then I need the bottom to be fixed for each page to show the Header/Cheque information.

So effectively the group footer needs to be floored to become the page footer.

However if there are only a few detail entries then the group header obviously rises up the page and would be well out of line from where it is meant to be.

So I need 1 group per page, table style I guess, but the group footer has to be at the bottom... fixed.